# Inbox is displayed as completely empty in Android app

Tags: bug, status-norepro, android-app, global-inbox

I opened up the Android app today and my inbox looked like this:

[image]

Nothing was displayed - and this is the second time in the last day or two that this has happened.

**Details:**

- Nexus 5
- Android 4.4 (Kit Kat)
- Stack Exchange App v0.1.73

Comment: Hmm, it shows up fine for me. I don't have pending notifications though. What happens if you swipe down to refresh the data?

Comment: In not sure. It only happens intermittently.

Comment: Are you able to pull and refresh it while it's empty? If so, does it still appear empty after the refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I think this had to do with our initial top-bar rollout, I haven't been able to reproduce it on my end since. If you can find it again let me know and I'll reopen this.